# ColdFusion: More efficient structKeyExists() instead of isDefined()

Tags: performance, optimization, coldfusion, cfml, premature-optimization

Which of these is more efficient in ColdFusion?

```
isDefined('url.myvar')
```

or

```
structKeyExists(url, 'myvar')
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

These days (CF8+) the difference in speed is not *that* great. However, `structKeyExists` is indeed a little faster. Here's why.

When you use `isDefined`, the string you pass in is searched for as a key name in several scopes. As of CF9, the list of scopes, in the order checked is: ([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20160312061318/http://fusiongrokker.com/post/scope-priority-changes-in-coldfusion-9))

1. Local (function local, UDFs and CFCs only)
2. Arguments
3. Thread local (inside threads only)
4. Query (not a true scope, applies for variables within query loops)
5. Thread
6. Variables
7. CGI
8. CFFile
9. URL
10. Form
11. Cookie
12. Client

Even if you use the scope name with `isDefined` (like: `if isDefined('variables.foo')`) the list will still be checked in order; and if the variable `local.variables.foo` is defined, it will be found *BEFORE* `variables.foo`.

On the other hand, `structKeyExists` only searches the structure you pass it for the existence of the key name; so there are far fewer places it will have to look.

By using more explicit code (`structKeyExists`), not only are you gaining some performance, but your code is more readable and maintainable, in my opinion.

Comment: Very good! It is interesting to see how it processes the functions differently.

Comment: I also think ColdFusion needs to run an eval on the string you provide. StructKeyExists avoids a lot of work.

Comment: There's one big problem with `structKeyExists()` though. If you deserialize a JSON string with ColdFusion and you have a property `myVal` with the value `null`, then `structKeyExists(object, "myVal")` will return `true`, while `isDefined("object.myVal")` will not. Or in other words, if you try to access the property with `object.myVal` after checking with `structKeyExists()`, you'll get an error.

Comment: True. But that's a bug in the way CF handles null. Try `isNull()` before your `structKeyExists()` call, whenever null is an acceptable value.

Answer (score 13):

Use the one which is **easier to read** and best shows what you're doing.

The difference between the two is *incredibly* small, and very likely not worth worrying about at all.

Don't waste time optimising code unless you have a ***proven* and *repeatable* test case** which demonstrates the slowness.

Comment: +1 . It is definitely worthwhile to understand *how* the two functions operate. But unless you have a 
performance problem, writing readable code that behaves correctly is far more important IMO.

Comment: I completely agree, but I am still a regular user of `structKeyExists`. I find that its explicit nature makes everything crystal clear, where `isDefined` does not always, which results in more time and headaches when coming back to old code (and/or someone else's code) months or years later.

Comment: Though IsDefined() is more intuitively named, what you just described is still a better reason to choose one over the other,than premature concerns about performance. At least IMHO ;-) – Leigh 8 mins ago

Comment: very late comment, but what i suggest it sometimes pages do time out due to this key issues, throws gateway errors