# Constructing a CFIF statement to display content when variable value is not blank

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am trying to write an If Statement where if `"session.checkout.info.abc_1Certificate_1"` exists and is not blank then show it. But if `"session.checkout.info.abc_1Certificate_1"` is blank don't show it.

This is what I have come up with but it is not working properly..

```
<cfif (len(trim("session.checkout.info.abc_1Certificate_1")))>
  Certificate:&nbsp;#session.checkout.info.abc_1Certificate_1#
</cfif>
```

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  In this case, add a cfelse block and output some variables and function results.  Start with len(trim("session.checkout.info.abc_1Certificate_1"))

Comment: Also, due to the double quotes, you are actually checking the length of the literal string `"session.checkout.info.abc_1Certificate_1"` - not the value of a session variable by that name...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<cfif isDefined("session.checkout.info.abc_1Certificate_1") 
       AND len(trim(session.checkout.info.abc_1Certificate_1))>
  Certificate:&nbsp;#session.checkout.info.abc_1Certificate_1#
<cfelse>
  session.checkout.info.abc_1Certificate_1 doesn't exist or is blank
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 4):

You really rather want something like this:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(session.checkout.info,"abc_1Certificate_1") AND len(trim(session.checkout.info.abc_1Certificate_1)) GT 0>
```

This is saying: if there is a key called `abc_1Certificate_1` in the structure `session.checkout.info` AND the length of the value of `session.checkout.info.abc_1Certificate_1` with any padding spaces removed is greater than 0, then...

If `session.checkout.info.abc_1Certificate_1` doesn't exist, then `len(trim(session.checkout.info.abc_1Certificate_1))` would normally throw an error, but since ColdFusion processes the part of the statement to the left of the `AND` first (and short-circuits the evaluation) CF won't bother to examine the rest of the statement.

Comment: See also: [ColdFusion: More efficient structKeyExists() instead of isDefined()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3956324/3524344)

Comment: *processes IF statements from left-to-right* Not quite. The logical `AND` operator is what causes the [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).